# Unable to access prometheus endpoint using the ip address after deployment using serviceaccount and rbac

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, grafana, kubernetes-rbac, servicemonitor

I am using this [link](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana-cloud/kubernetes-monitoring/prometheus/prometheus_operator/) to set up Prometheus using servicemonitoring and RBAC rules.

After deployment, I am trying to access prometheus endpoint using `http://<ipaddress_server>:32001` to display the metrics.

I am also trying to add the prometheus datasource in grafana ( running on same node) as `http://localhost:32001` or `http://localhost:9090`, but both didn't work.

```
$ kubectl get svc -A | grep prom
default                prometheus                                 NodePort       10.XX.XX.XX   <none>         9090:32001/TCP                        14m
default                prometheus-operated                        ClusterIP      None             <none>         9090/TCP                              14m
default                prometheus-operator                        ClusterIP      None             <none>         8080/TCP                              15m
```

kubectl get deployment
NAME                  READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
prometheus-operator   1/1     1            1           3h7m

```
kubectl get deployment
NAME                  READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
prometheus-operator   1/1     1            1           3h7m


kubectl get pods -A | grep prom
default                prometheus-operator-5dc8bc6f9c-9lwtw                              1/1     Running             0                 3h7m
default                prometheus-prometheus-0                                           2/2     Running             0                 3h6m
default                prometheus-prometheus-1                                           2/2     Running    

kubectl get servicemonitor
NAME              AGE
prometheus-self   3h4m
     0                 3h6m
```

I also tried port forwarding using below command:

```
kubectl port-forward svc/prometheus 9090
```

But, it doesn't show anything.

Please help, as I am new to kubernetes and also prometheus and grafana.

Answer (score 0):

Try to create ConfigMap with following Configuration and Apply it will work.

> ConfigMap is generally used to provide Runtime Configurations to our
> Applications(Pods) but make sure you shouldn't use ConfigMap to
> provide credentials, use Secrets instead.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: grafana-datasources
data:
  prometheus.yaml: |-
   {
    "apiVersion": 1,
    "datasources": [
        {
           "access":"proxy",
            "editable": true,
            "name": "prometheus",
            "orgId": 1,
            "type": "prometheus",
            "url": "http://prometheus-operated.default.svc:9090",
            "version": 1
        },
    ]
}
```

Here What I tried instead of using localhost:9090 used service name and namespace name along with Port number as Host DNS.

```
"http://serviceName.NamespaceName.svc:port"
```

But you can't access above URL in browser.

After Applying this ConfigMap you can check your Grafana Dashboard by Port-Forwarding  `kubectl port-forward svc/grafana 3000`

You can Follow this https://github.com/prometheus-operator/kube-prometheus/blob/main/manifests/grafana-dashboardSources.yaml